# Actionscript iterate through IList

Tags: apache-flex, collections, actionscript

I have an ArrayCollection which might be filtered. To get the raw data I am getting IList. But when I use for each over IList it jumps out of the loop. I am sure that there is data in array collection.

```
private var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();


protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var p:Person;

    for (var i:int = 1; i<= 10; i++)
    {
        p = new Person();
        p.age = i;
        p.name = name + " " + i;
        ac.addItem(p);
    }


    for each (var p in ac.list)
    {
        trace (p.name);
    }

}
```

My question is how can I iterate through IList.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for index loop to loop over an iList; but not a `for each` loop:

```
for(var index:int = 0;index<iListInstance.length  ; index++){
  var element : Person = iListInstance.getItemAt(index);
  trace(element.name);
}
```